# How can I add/remove an element to/from the first td of the table before text?

Tags: jquery

I have a div with id (titlediv_1265601). How can I add/remove a *  to the first td of the table before "Adjuster Name:" based on the following condition using jquery?

```
        if(a == 'addSpan')
        {}
        else if(a == 'RemoveSpan')
        {}
<div id="titlediv_1265601" style="width: 100%; position: relative; visibility: visible; display: block;">
            <table> 
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td id="AdjusterOrAdjusterAssistantCell" class="MyTableHeadingCell">Adjuster Name:</td>
                        <td class="MyTableTagsCell"><input type="text" id="AdjusterOrAdjusterAssistant"></td>
                        <td class="MyTableHeadingCell"></td>
                         <td class="MyTableTagsCell"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#AdjusterOrAdjusterAssistantCell")
       .prepend('<span class="Required" title="Required">* </span>');
```

will probably work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly: You can use the [`:first-child`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-child) pseudo selector to access the first `<td>` in the table, and then jQuery's [`prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)` to prepend your desired content.

```
$('#titlediv_1265601 table td:first-child').prepend('<span class=“Required” title=“Required”>* </span>');
```

Answer (score 0):

To add:

```
$("#AdjusterOrAdjusterAssistantCell").prepend('<span class="Required" title="Required">*</span>');
```

To remove:

```
$("#AdjusterOrAdjusterAssistantCell span").remove();
```